# positive-definite matrix with equal row sums

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices

Consider the following square matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} \\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} \\
a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} \\
a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4}
\end{bmatrix}
where $0\leq a_{i,j} \leq 1$ for all $i,j \in [1,16]$. Consider some $\delta >0$, I know that this matrix satisfies 
\begin{align}
\left| \sum_{j=1}^4 a_{i,j} - \frac{1}{4} \sum_{i=1}^4 \sum_{j=1}^4 a_{i,j} \right| \leq \delta \quad \text{for all } i \in [1,4],
\end{align}
that is, all the row sums *almost* equal to the sum of all elements divided by the number of rows (or columns).

**QUESTION:** The previous property implies 
\begin{align}
\left| \sum_{i=1}^4 a_{i,j} - \frac{1}{4} \sum_{i=1}^4 \sum_{j=1}^4 a_{i,j} \right| \leq \delta \quad \text{for all } j \in [1,4],
\end{align}
**?????????**

Answer (score 1):

No, there are easy counter examples:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$$